# File won't run from command prompt that is on network drive

Tags: python, networking

I have an .exe file that we normally open from a desktop shortcut.  However, I am now wanting to open it through Python.  I am using the following:

```
import subprocess <br/>
subprocess.call(['S:\\file.exe'])
```

That opened the file, however, the file has dependencies that are on that network drive (S:) and it seems that it is trying to run from the C drive so while the program starts, it throws a fit of errors.

How can I make the program run from the command line, or within python and still find its own dependencies from the S: drive?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for ideas on how to construct a better questions so that we can help

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  I read the "how to ask" section, but am confused about what in my question needs clarification.  If you will tell me where you feel clarification is needed, I will gladly comply.

Comment: no you didn't you have not yet read

Comment: Sanoj, now you have told me that I tell lies.  Please comment elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which directory are you running the script from?

You might have to `chdir` to the `S:` drive:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("S:")
subprocess.call(['S:\file.exe'])
```

Comment: I am running the script from the C:\sikuli directory.  os.chdir("S:") gave me the error: "OSError((2,'No such file or directory','C:\\sikuli\\S:'))

Comment: Strange, `chdir` works for me on windows - can you try `os.chdir("S:\\")`?

Comment: Boom! that fixed it, guess I needed the two backslashes.  THANKS A TON Vikramls!  Would vote up, but not enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

try with file name as 'S:/file.exe'

Comment: Thanks Craig.  I tried that from the command prompt and the program blew up.  From the errors it gives, it seems to be depending on files on the S: and is looking for them in the wrong places.

Comment: so you can't call the executable with a Fully Qualified Path, it seems like it is looking for some config file relative to your current working directory .... you have to change the working directory to be where it expects you to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call(['S:\\file.exe'], cwd='S:\\')
```